# Azure application gateway with AKS Kube-Proxy

Tags: azure-aks, azure-cloud-services, azure-application-gateway

I have a AKS Cluster and some microservice with Nodeport available in it.

```
User -> Application Gateway -> Backend Pool -> Nodeport of microservice -> service
```

However, i have idea to use Application Gateway with Virtual machine scale sets from AKS Node Pool.

When i add backend (VMSS) of AKS Nodepool in application gateway

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "LinkedAuthorizationFailed",
        "message": "The client has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/galleries/images/versions/read' on scope '/subscriptions/aa51d057-842e..../resourcegroups/MC_loadbalancer_aaa-aks-1_southeastasia/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/aks-syspool-13675031-vmss', however the current tenant '1393b73d-faec-...' is not authorized to access linked subscription '911a5e88-712a-...'."
    }
}
```

But if i create manual VMSS and add it to application gateway, it's fine. But when i add VMSS Node Pool by AKS Cluster, it's error like above.

The error is weird. It's like my Tenant ID doesn't have subscription to 911a5e88....

Is it really possible to connect application gateway to AKS Node Pool as backend-pool ?

Comment: How do you add VMSS Node Pool by AKS Cluster?

Comment: I scale up it through Kubernetes Service AKS Cluster. There is a menu called "Node pools". It's created automatically by AKS Azure.

Comment: This  "Node pools" means you can add new node pool for AKS, how do you face this error? Also, I am confused about "But if i create manual VMSS and add it to application gateway, it's fine.".

Comment: I mean, when i add VMSS created by AKS Cluster into Backend Pool of Application gateway, i got error like above. But, when i created dummy VMSS by myself and add it into Backend Pool of Application gateway, i didn't get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in the exact same situation.

The fix was inspired from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#update-the-load-balancer-for-your-scale-set It seems like in azure you can go also the other way around and configure your VMSS to a BackendPool, option which seems to be available only from the CLI.

```
az vmss update --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myScaleSet --add virtualMachineProfile.networkProfile.networkInterfaceConfigurations[0].ipConfigurations[0].ApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPools '{"id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/{applicationGatewayName}/backendAddressPools/{applicationGatewayBackendPoolName}"}'
```

I don't know why the current reply was accepted since it just providing an workaround; you must be able to add a VMSS to your AppGW backend pool. It's either a bug in Azure or an undocumented case with the latest upgrades.

You should never use IP or FQDN with a VMSS, it's not good practice.

Comment: Good suggestion. It works. By using az vmss update, i can point my vmss into backend pool. If you do it by using azure portal, it will be error.

Comment: For any googlers out there, this should not be the case anymore, it should work from UI.

Answer (score 1):

I also face the issue when directly add the node pool to the backend pool. From [Ingress controller creates backend pool based on pod IP not the service IP](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/524), it seems that you can directly target the node IP to the backend pool of application gateway. You can select the Target type `IP address or FQDN`. Your App Gateway must be in the same VNet as your AKS.

[image]

For more information, if you are interested in creating an Application Gateway ingress controller in Azure Kubernetes Service, you can [create them with terraform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/create-k8s-cluster-with-aks-applicationgateway-ingress) and [troubleshoot common questions or issues with Ingress Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-troubleshoot).

Comment: Thank you very much, Nancy. Awesome ! This is what i want. My company is still providing many POCs as much as my team can before move to Azure completely. I think add Node worker IP Address manually is not best practice. I wish i can add Node pool (VMSS) rather than IP Address. But application gateway is still recommended in my opinion.

EDIT: I can use FQDN rather than ip address